# How do I create a column that is a concatenation of two other columns in mariadb?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am redesigning a database that my manager made as I my first project after being promoted to IT. I started by copying everything over and cleaning it up. I noticed later that the "Employees" table had columns for first name and last name, but all the other tables reference the employees by their full name, they need to be relational, so I wanted to change the Employee List table to use full name only and get rid of the unnecessary columns for first name and last name.

I have tried to concatenate the first and last name columns into one column, but the only times that I have used correct mariadb syntax the tables only show 0 in the field. Here are some examples of what has not worked:

Result is 0:

```
ALTER TABLE employees
ADD COLUMN Employee VARCHAR(50)
AS (first_name || ' ' || last_name);

UPDATE TABLE employees
SET Employee = first_name + last_name;
```

I'm assuming this doesn't work because it is for numbers, there would also be no space.

Syntax error:

```
ALTER TABLE employees
ADD COLUMN Employee VARCHAR(50)
AS (first_name, ' ', || last_name);
```

error in ' ' ', last_name)' This syntax only works for CONCAT, but that doesn't seem to work here either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply:

```
ALTER TABLE employees 
ADD COLUMN Employee VARCHAR(100) AS (CONCAT(first_name, ' ' , last_name));
```

Comment: That did work! That makes a bit of sense it use another set of parenthesis around CONCAT.

Comment: Well, I think it only partially worked -- `AS` is `VIRTUAL` by default, so the column is, in some sense, not really there.  But `VIRTUAL` may be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CONCAT_WS()`:

```
ALTER TABLE employees ADD COLUMN Employee VARCHAR(50) AS (CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, last_name);
```

`CONCAT_WS()` handles `NULL` values.

Note:  You will not be able to remove the underlying columns, because your computed column depends on them.

In MariaDB:

- `||` is a logical operator.  It will treat your values as boolean expressions -- hence converting them to numbers.
- `+` is addition.  It also treats the values as numbers, which are converted to `0`.

Comment: I used CONCAT and it turned out how I wanted, but what would CONCAT_WS do differently? Entering it in a query looks the same. Assuming there is any difference at all

Comment: @ZenRen . . . As I say, it handles `NULL` values the way that you want them handled.  That is, it *ignores* the `NULL` values rather than returning `NULL`.

Comment: I see. I have only been using sql for a few days, I have not quite caught onto what the NULL values do. I see they can be used in queries, but I'm not sure for what reason, at least in my case. I can change the NULL value if I need to, but I know the first_name and last_name columns I had previously had the same value because I just left them that way.

Comment: @ZenRen . . . The point is that `employee` doesn't become `null` just because one of the input values is `null`.

Comment: None of them are currently and the first_name and last_name columns are gone. If another employee is added to the list later they probably should have a name, I won't be the one using this database later though, who knows what they will do. Is not NULL something that should normally be added to a VARCHAR?