# How do I create a column that is a concatenation of two other columns FROM ANOTHER TABLE in mariadb (mysql)?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

The following link asks a similar question, except I need to create a virtual column in table A that combines data from a column in table A and a column in table B. Is this possible?

link: [How do I create a column that is a concatenation of two other columns in mariadb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57615722/how-do-i-create-a-column-that-is-a-concatenation-of-two-other-columns-in-mariadb)

Unfortunately this site doesn't allow me to comment on the existing page since I do not have points; in any case this question is a bit different from that page so I hope this new question is accepted.

Comment: In MySQL it is not possible to use a virtual column to query another table. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html starting at the paragraph "Generated column expressions must adhere to the following rules."

Comment: You could do what you want using a trigger.