# How to create a new column in table that is the concatenation of others

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation, multiple-columns

Used the following but to no avail ([How do I create a column that is a concatenation of two other columns in mariadb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57615722/how-do-i-create-a-column-that-is-a-concatenation-of-two-other-columns-in-mariadb))

The task appears to be simple but it is eluding me. I have six columns that I need to be concatenated into one column

```
censusstate char(2)
censuscounty  char(3)
censustrac   char(6)
censusblocgroup char(1)
censusbloccode char(2)
censusbloccode2 char(1) 

end result   should be censusbloc char(15)
```

tried the following code but get errors

```
   alter table dbo.equi2022t
   add censusbloc char(15) AS 
 (Concat(CensusState,CensusCounty,Censustrac,Censusblocgroup,Censusbloccode,Censusbloccode2));


 Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 364
 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
```

Comment: Don't say you "get errors" without telling us what the errors are...

Comment: Are you using SQL Server database?

Comment: Please see [Why should I tag my RDBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL server support computed columns, but need some special syntax

```
  alter table dbo.equi2022t
   add censusbloc   
   AS (CensusState + CensusCounty + Censustrac + Censusblocgroup + Censusbloccode + Censusbloccode2)
 ;
```